# Is this a mac virus? background items added "Open"

Tags: macos, process

I'm getting alerts on my mac. background items added "Open", which links to a terminal app called "Open" from unidentified developer.

What is that? Should I delete it? It's impossible to search google for as it's got such a vague name.

Comment: And I'm afraid this is a vague description. Can you please give more details, like the exact messages you see, or screenshots?

Comment: Anyway, this is likely off-topic for StackOverflow. You're going to have a better chance at settings answers at [Apple.SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a source connecting it to Adobe CC and explaining both how to verify it (i.e. making sure that it is not malicious) and removing it (if still intended): https://www.droidwin.com/remove-open-from-allow-in-the-background-on-mac/

Side note: Getting more and more annoyed by Adobe software on a Mac, every day.

Answer (score 0):

I just started getting the same pop up message today. This isn't even listed in my login items.[Background Items Open Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjohB.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).